# Facebook Page details and the RESTful API?

Tags: python, facebook, pyfacebook

Hi I have a list of Facebook Page urls

```
eg...
http://www.facebook.com/daftpunk
http://www.facebook.com/DavidGuetta
...
```

What's the best way to:

- Check if these urls are ***actually*** for Facebook Pages and ***not*** Profiles
- Collect details such as ***# of fans*** from these Pages

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without scraping any content (which is against Facebook's terms of service anyway):

1. Extract the username part of the URL
   i.e. the bit after the
   www.facebook.com/
2. Do an FQL query of the form `select
   fan_count  from
   page where
   username='michaeljackson'`
3. If a result is return, you know it's a
   Page and not a user's profile.

See the [Page FQL table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Page_%28FQL%29) for other data you can retrieve in the same call.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done! Thanks though, would have have very helpful yesterday. upvoted

Answer (score 2):

use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or [pyfacebook](http://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/) to fetch the content

use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) to parse it

use the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module (regular expressions) to extract content for your verification and data gathering

Comment: sorry still doesn't help me to get **# of fans** :(

Comment: you have to extract that yourself.  perhaps using regular expressions.  updated the answer.

Comment: ok, I found out how to get the # of fans, the field value is not referenced in the RESTful API you can check yourself here http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Pages.getInfo#Response

The fan_count is available in FQL queries instead. Are you proposing to scrape the url and therefore to mine for data with BeautifulSoup or lxml?

Answer (score 1):

The # of fans is in an a tag with the class 'FanManager'. you can use Beautiful Soup to get the contents of this a tag, and regular expressions to get the data from the string (ex: 1,000,000 fans) as an int or whatever you would like.

To see if the page exists, check some of the tags to see if you are on the 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to scrape the content.